# copy in clipboard only the field in pivotgrid

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I'm searching a way to copy inside the clipboard when the user click on a row (or columns) field.
Example: When the user click on the row(or columns) "hello world" and press on ctrl+c it fill the clipboard with "hello world".

thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/637ys738.aspx

Comment: Well the real problem is not to add data inside the clipboard. The problem is that i cannot found anyway to select the data that i need to copy

Comment: Are you using DataGrid? if so, you can get specific values for the selected item using `DataGrid.SelectedItem` property. More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.selecteditem.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Comment: No im using PivotGrid in winforms

Comment: You can get the column index and the row index of a cell that's been clicked through the CellClick event: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxPivotGridScriptsASPxClientPivotGrid_CellClicktopic I couldn't find an event for column/row clicked. is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes it is. That's why i am posting this question cause i need to keep the event of a cell click for another operation. My application is in Winforms and not in Asp.Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a way to do it. On the event of MouseClick on PivotGridControl.

> Dim _point As Point = Nothing

```
Private Sub PivotGridControl1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles PivotGridControl1.KeyDown
    If _point.IsEmpty Then
    Else
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.C AndAlso e.Control Then
            Dim field As DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.PivotFieldValueHitInfo = PivotGridControl1.CalcHitInfo(_point).ValueInfo
            Clipboard.SetText(field.Value.ToString())
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PivotGridControl1_MouseClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PivotGridControl1.MouseClick
    PivotGridControl1.OptionsBehavior.CopyToClipboardWithFieldValues = True

    Dim pt As Point = New Point(e.X, e.Y)

    If PivotGridControl1.CalcHitInfo(pt).HitTest = DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.PivotGridHitTest.Value Then
        _point = pt
    Else
        _point = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the `Ctrl + C` shortcut for copying and what I do is that I handle the `KeyDown` event for my WinForm control :

```
private static void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Retrieve sender + view here

    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(view.GetFocusedDisplayText());
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps !